# Merge query inserting but not updating on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa

I've got this query in a *@SQLInsert* annotation in Spring against an Oracle 11g database and, although it's inserting properly it is not updating the values but raising no error.

Any ideas? If not, any alternative ways of obtaining same behaviour?

```
merge INTO ngram sn
USING(SELECT ? AS frequency,
             ? AS occurrences,
             ? AS ngram
      FROM   dual) src
ON (sn.ngram = src.ngram)
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE SET sn.occurrences = sn.occurrences + src.occurrences,
             sn.frequency = sn.frequency + 1
WHEN NOT matched THEN
  INSERT (ngram,
          frequency,
          occurrences)
  VALUES (src.ngram,
          src.frequency,
          src.occurrences)
```

**Update1:** I'm adding the Entity def in Java for clarification.

```
@Entity(name = "NGRAM")
public class Ngram
{
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("ngram")
    private String ngram;

    @JsonProperty("frequency")
    @Column(name = "frequency")
    private int frequency;

    @JsonProperty("occurrences")
    @Column(name = "occurrences")
    private int occurrences;
```

**Update2:** Adding a run of the SQL query on an existing Ngram

```
sql> merge INTO NGRAM sn
     USING(SELECT 1 AS frequency,
                  200 AS occurrences,
                  'year' AS ngram
           FROM   dual) src
     ON (sn.ngram = src.ngram)
     WHEN matched THEN
       UPDATE SET sn.occurrences = sn.occurrences + src.occurrences,
                  sn.frequency = sn.frequency + 1
     WHEN NOT matched THEN
       INSERT (ngram,
               frequency,
               occurrences)
       VALUES (src.ngram,
               src.frequency,
               src.occurrences)
[2019-01-29 12:09:10] 1 row affected in 19 ms
```

This actually modifies the row, but not when I go over them in the code, so it seems the SQL is right...

**Update3:** So, this is the piece of code that should be inserting or updating but it's only doing the insert:

```
    List<Ngram> lNgrams = new ArrayList<>(lCollocationsMap.size());
    lCollocationsMap.forEach((pKey, pValue) -> lNgrams.add( new Ngram(pKey, 1, pValue)));
    mNgramRepo.saveAll(lNgrams);
```

So I'll be investigating the *saveAll* behaviour.

**Update4:** I tried using *save* one by one which is much slower instead of using *saveAll* but got same behaviour. Changing *ON (sn.ngram = src.ngram)* to *ON (sn.ngram LIKE src.ngram)* makes some of the frequencies to become 2 (so they seem to be updated) but not all of them: 'year' for example appears more than 10 times but it's frequency remains 1 and it's occurrences is just updated with last value found.

So, I'm now completely lost on why this is failing, specially in this way.

Comment: Run a `10046 trace`with `level 4` (trace bind variable) to see what is going on. What datatype is `ngram` and what value and type (`setXxxxx`) you pass in?

Comment: Ngram is a string. I'll update with the entity definition. I'll have to look up for the 10046 trace with level 4 and setXxxxx 'cause that all sounds new to me sadly.

Comment: Second one seems to be ignored.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that in the trace when writting the query. If not it wouldn't even be able to insert, would it?

Comment: @epsilonmajorquezero If it does only the `INSERT`, it surely means `WHEN matched THEN ` is not satisfying the condition. Try printing the bind variables and execute from the backend.

Comment: Well, I've been debugging a bit deeper and it's actually overriding the occurrences value, not leaving the first one.

Comment: Well, changed ON (sn.ngram = src.ngram)  = to LIKE and now some of them get their frequency incremented but now I got an error, I believe because one of the ngram strings is % and wasn't scaped.

Comment: Still, the ones that get updated do not seem consistenc in different runs and since running the query directly into the DB seems to work to me all of this points to some weird behavior with Transactions management from save/saveAll functions :S

Comment: just asking, do you have a commit statement in the update clause?

Comment: Well, that is now a bit old and I don't remember the details but I would say I didn't have. You are seeing pretty much all the code involved in this and I don't work anymore on that project.